# Functions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function

How I can to pass a function from application_controller to application.html.erb?

I have a left bar in application.html.erb and I have to show some links. In the application_controller I have some vars and I want to pass them to a application.html.erb. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

`Q1: How I can to pass a function from application_controller to application.html.erb?`

A. You cannot pass a method from controller to view, instead you can write a method in helper. Only helper method are accessible from View.

`Q2: In the application_controller I have some vars and I want to pass them to a application.html.erb.`

A. You can use instance variable in controller. Instance variables are accessible in view. To use instance variables, put `@` before variable name in your controller, for eg: @name="Manchester United" or @food_preferences = FoodPreference.all and then use @name or @food_preferences in your view(in your case its application.html.erb) with ruby tag.

Comment: I have to pass thes vars in application.html.erb: food_preferences = FoodPreference.all, food_types = FoodType.all and cuisines = Cuisine.all